# Very long boot up in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04

I upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. I am experiencing very slow boot up times. It takes about 2+ minutes to fully boot up.

I have tried looking for some solutions by myself, but I am not sure on what to do to speed up the start up process.

Here is the log from systemd-analyze:

```
Startup finished in 5.706s (kernel) + 1min 43.625s (userspace) = 1min 49.331s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 43.609s in userspace
```

Here is the log from systemd-analyze blame:

```
58.970s mysql.service                            
57.405s udisks2.service                          
46.492s plymouth-quit-wait.service               
30.941s snapd.service                            
27.644s networkd-dispatcher.service              
25.554s dev-sda6.device                          
23.983s systemd-journal-flush.service            
21.631s accounts-daemon.service                  
18.247s apache2.service                          
18.116s dev-loop8.device                         
17.584s dev-loop13.device                        
17.547s dev-loop10.device                        
16.902s dev-loop12.device                        
16.843s dev-loop11.device                        
16.838s dev-loop7.device                         
16.532s dev-loop9.device                         
16.344s NetworkManager-wait-online.service       
15.978s dev-loop6.device                         
15.870s dev-loop5.device                         
15.614s ModemManager.service                     
15.110s dev-loop0.device                         
13.675s dev-loop1.device                         
12.752s dev-loop4.device                         
12.680s dev-loop3.device                         
12.250s NetworkManager.service                   
10.742s avahi-daemon.service                     
10.734s bluetooth.service                        
10.460s dev-loop2.device                         
10.402s polkit.service                           
 9.641s switcheroo-control.service               
 9.595s systemd-logind.service                   
 9.579s thermald.service                         
 9.565s wpa_supplicant.service                   
 6.634s systemd-resolved.service                 
 5.818s systemd-udevd.service                    
 5.806s gpu-manager.service                      
 5.065s gdm.service                              
 5.010s colord.service                           
 4.633s plymouth-read-write.service              
 4.490s apport.service                           
 4.489s grub-common.service                      
 4.314s user@1000.service                        
 4.194s rsyslog.service                          
 4.178s apparmor.service                         
 3.929s e2scrub_reap.service                     
 3.629s systemd-rfkill.service                   
 2.280s grub-initrd-fallback.service             
 1.876s snapd.apparmor.service                   
 1.754s networking.service                       
 1.593s fwupd.service                            
 1.432s upower.service                           
 1.294s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service           
 1.110s pppd-dns.service                         
 1.107s systemd-sysusers.service                 
 1.058s systemd-journald.service                 
 1.022s systemd-modules-load.service             
  913ms snap-core-8935.mount                     
  856ms snap-core-9066.mount                     
  855ms systemd-sysctl.service                   
  806ms packagekit.service                       
  805ms snap-core18-1668.mount                   
  789ms keyboard-setup.service                   
  771ms systemd-timesyncd.service                
  693ms snap-core18-1705.mount                   
  690ms systemd-udev-trigger.service             
  682ms nvidia-persistenced.service              
  633ms snapd.seeded.service                     
  631ms openvpn.service                          
  624ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service       
  613ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-92.mount   
  598ms systemd-random-seed.service              
  589ms ufw.service                              
  582ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-98.mount   
  570ms dns-clean.service                        
  520ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-110.mount  
  494ms swapfile.swap                            
  494ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount  
  381ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-27.mount   
  368ms plymouth-start.service                   
  330ms modprobe@drm.service                     
  314ms kerneloops.service                       
  266ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-127.mount
  263ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-135.mount
  259ms systemd-remount-fs.service               
  250ms phpsessionclean.service                  
  225ms console-setup.service                    
  225ms systemd-user-sessions.service            
  215ms dev-hugepages.mount                      
  213ms dev-mqueue.mount                         
  211ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                   
  210ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                 
  209ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount  
  206ms kmod-static-nodes.service                
  197ms snap-snap\x2dstore-433.mount             
  187ms setvtrgb.service                         
  182ms ifupdown-pre.service                     
  172ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service            
  165ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1474.mount  
  145ms rtkit-daemon.service                     
  125ms systemd-update-utmp.service              
   35ms ureadahead-stop.service                  
   22ms alsa-restore.service                     
   10ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service     
    8ms sys-kernel-config.mount                  
    5ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount            
    3ms snapd.socket
```

Here is the log from systemd-analyze critical-chain:

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 43.609s
└─multi-user.target @1min 43.609s
  └─mysql.service @44.637s +58.970s
    └─network.target @44.628s
      └─NetworkManager.service @32.376s +12.250s
        └─dbus.service @32.364s
          └─basic.target @32.122s
            └─sockets.target @32.122s
              └─snapd.socket @32.117s +3ms
                └─sysinit.target @31.803s
                  └─systemd-timesyncd.service @31.031s +771ms
                    └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @29.674s +1.294s
                      └─systemd-journal-flush.service @5.690s +23.983s
                        └─systemd-journald.service @4.629s +1.058s
                          └─systemd-journald.socket @4.620s
                            └─system.slice @4.585s
                              └─-.slice @4.585s
```

---

EDIT #1:

Added log from journalctl -b -u udisks2 -u mysql

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-01-15 17:31:37 EST, end at Wed 2020-04-29 19:09:14 EDT. --
Apr 29 17:06:12 ubuntupet-Inspiron-537 systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
Apr 29 17:06:16 ubuntupet-Inspiron-537 udisksd[806]: udisks daemon version 2.8.4 starting
Apr 29 17:06:24 ubuntupet-Inspiron-537 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Apr 29 17:06:28 ubuntupet-Inspiron-537 udisksd[806]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Apr 29 17:06:30 ubuntupet-Inspiron-537 udisksd[806]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
Apr 29 17:07:09 ubuntupet-Inspiron-537 systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.
Apr 29 17:07:09 ubuntupet-Inspiron-537 udisksd[806]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
Apr 29 17:07:21 ubuntupet-Inspiron-537 systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

I am not sure on how to proceed now.

---

EDIT #2:

I have uploaded the log from the following command onto Dropbox due to the large amount of lines.
`journalctl -S "2020-04-29 17:06:30"`

Here is the link to the direct log file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8jbtwgc09vddsg/log5.txt?dl=0

It seems that there are a lot of app armor denied errors.

---

EDIT #3:

I have been unable to find what the cause of the problem is. I have done a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04. The boot up process is down to ~1:20.

Comment: Do a reinstall of Ubuntu and see if something changes

Comment: Wow - your edit shows how important it is to share all information. I'd given a better answer if I had seen this. So you have a mraid installed? Describe how you configured them

Comment: I have not configured any raid devices. The computer has only one harddrive. I have uploaded another log from the journalctl command. Perhaps, it can help pinpoint the problem(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd install Ubuntu 20.04 off the scratch. It looks like your "upgrade" borked something. "systemd-analyze blame" shows exactly, where your time goes... And waiting for mySql for a minute does not make sense at all. My output for udisk2 for example is

> 406ms udisks2.service

So save your data and install it freshly.

Comment: Same with a fresh Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 5):

As a next step, you may look up the logs of mysql and udisks2, as they seem to take the longest here.

The command `journalctl -b -u udisks2 -u mysql` should be useful for that.

Comment: I have attached the output of the journalctl command. It seems that mdraid fails to load.

Comment: There is still this gap between 17:06:30 and 17:07:09. Maybe `journalctl -S "2020-04-29 17:06:30"`, without confinement to the unit, can reveal more.

If it's really mdraid: Did you configure any raid devices?

Comment: I have not setup any raid devices. There is only one harddrive in the PC (It is partitioned with a small Windows partition and the rest is for Ubuntu). I have edited my post with the link to the log from the journalctl command.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on an upgraded 20.04 system and never solved it. I since did a fresh reformatted install of 'Groovy Gorilla' 20.10 and boot/shutdown speeds are amazing, the best I have ever seen on any version of Linux or Windows.

Comment: You probably didn't need to reinstall 20.10. Orphaned packages from 20.04 could have caused the slow boot/shutdown speeds. Search for orphaned packages with deborphan and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to help me remove some orphaned packages - https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/remove-orphaned-packages-ubuntu/. Afterward my shutdowm and startup performance was much better.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it got fixed when I updated the kernel from 5.4 to 5.9 using [Check and Update Ubuntu Kernel Version on Ubuntu 20.04 – Linux Hint](https://linuxhint.com/update_ubuntu_kernel_20_04/)

Comment: In this case, the issue is that MySQL takes one minute to start. Installing an unsupported kernel may not be a solution.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the ownership of `/`:

   ```
   stat /
   ```
2. If you get something like:

   ```
   Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (1000/ username   Gid: (1000/       username)
   ```

   then change the ownership of `/`:

   ```
   chown root:root /
   ```
3. Reboot.