# 20.04 LTS takes too much time to load

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04

### system specs - Intel i5-8th gen,16 gb ram,4 GB NVIDIA graphics ,dual boot windows 10 in SSD Linux in HDD

i have used commands systemd-analyze . output is

> Startup finished in 9.677s (firmware) + 32.647s (loader) + 5.432s (kernel) + 1min 39.745s (userspace) = 2min 27.503s
> graphical.target reached after 1min 39.676s in userspace

systemd -analyze critical-chain. output is

> graphical.target @1min 39.676s
> └─multi-user.target @1min 39.676s
> └─kerneloops.service @52.451s +125ms
> └─network-online.target @52.394s
> └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @39.244s +13.148s
> └─NetworkManager.service @30.499s +8.743s
> └─dbus.service @30.496s
> └─basic.target @30.243s
> └─sockets.target @30.243s
> └─snapd.socket @30.243s +528us
> └─sysinit.target @29.985s
> └─snapd.apparmor.service @29.385s +600ms
> └─apparmor.service @27.758s +1.625s
> └─local-fs.target @27.758s
> └─run-user-121-gvfs.mount @57.463s
> └─run-user-121.mount @51.137s
> └─local-fs-pre.target @7.504s
> └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @7.166s +338ms
> └─systemd-sysusers.service @6.207s +958ms
> └─systemd-remount-fs.service @5.764s +439ms
> └─systemd-journald.socket @5.670s
> └─system.slice @5.667s
> └─-.slice @5.667s

also system -analyze blame. output is

> 1min 111ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
> 21.570s dev-sda5.device
> 19.827s systemd-journal-flush.service
> 18.695s snapd.service
> 17.418s udisks2.service
> 15.329s networkd-dispatcher.service
> 14.471s gpu-manager.service
> 14.389s accounts-daemon.service
> 13.148s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
> 11.756s dev-loop6.device
> 11.384s dev-loop15.device
> 11.252s dev-loop16.device
> 10.807s fwupd.service
> 9.850s dev-loop7.device
> 9.808s dev-loop9.device
> 9.678s dev-loop10.device
> 9.553s dev-loop13.device
> 9.547s dev-loop12.device
> 9.533s dev-loop14.device
> 9.496s dev-loop11.device
> 9.031s dev-loop17.device
> 8.900s polkit.service
> 8.752s avahi-daemon.service
> 8.747s bluetooth.service
> 8.743s NetworkManager.service
> 8.617s dev-loop3.device
> 8.383s switcheroo-control.service
> 8.379s thermald.service
> 8.376s systemd-logind.service
> 8.374s wpa_supplicant.service
> 7.924s dev-loop8.device
> 7.528s dev-loop0.device
> 7.359s dev-loop18.device
> 5.733s ModemManager.service
> 5.474s dev-loop1.device
> 5.451s dev-loop4.device
> 5.416s dev-loop2.device
> 5.376s dev-loop5.device
> 5.277s bolt.service
> 4.734s grub-common.service
> 4.597s apport.service
> 3.230s systemd-udevd.service
> 3.089s rsyslog.service
> 3.045s systemd-resolved.service
> 2.554s e2scrub_reap.service
> 2.377s packagekit.service
> 2.173s plymouth-start.service
> 2.122s systemd-sysctl.service
> 1.903s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
> 1.625s apparmor.service
> 1.612s grub-initrd-fallback.service
> 1.377s gdm.service
> 1.175s snap-core-9665.mount
> 1.136s snap-core-9804.mount
> 1.124s colord.service
> 1.091s systemd-rfkill.service
> 1.085s systemd-modules-load.service
> 1.065s snap-core18-1880.mount
> 1.064s snap-core18-1885.mount
> 958ms systemd-sysusers.service
> 940ms systemd-random-seed.service
> 908ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
> 903ms user@121.service
> 825ms snap-vlc-1700.mount
> 824ms systemd-journald.service
> 817ms keyboard-setup.service
> 780ms lm-sensors.service
> 670ms systemd-timesyncd.service
> 645ms snap-core20-634.mount
> 643ms nvidia-persistenced.service
> 619ms snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-2064.mount
> 600ms snapd.apparmor.service
> 570ms upower.service
> 564ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dcore18-32.mount
> 544ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-110.mount
> 534ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
> 524ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1440.mount
> 521ms snap-snap\x2dstore-454.mount
> 512ms snap-vlc-1620.mount
> 504ms atd.service
> 455ms ufw.service
> 449ms snap-snap\x2dstore-467.mount
> 439ms systemd-remount-fs.service
> 422ms snapd.seeded.service
> 410ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount
> 402ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount
> 390ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount
> 367ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-123.mount
> 360ms snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-1708.mount
> 338ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
> 314ms systemd-user-sessions.service
> 312ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-148.mount
> 289ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-92E6\x2d1211.service
> 270ms user@1000.service
> 251ms modprobe@drm.service
> 222ms swapfile.swap
> 210ms openvpn.service
> 209ms systemd-update-utmp.service
> 169ms console-setup.service
> 148ms kmod-static-nodes.service
> 125ms kerneloops.service
> 124ms rtkit-daemon.service
> 96ms dev-hugepages.mount
> 95ms dev-mqueue.mount
> 94ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
> 94ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
> 85ms boot-efi.mount
> 82ms pppd-dns.service
> 81ms hddtemp.service
> 76ms plymouth-read-write.service
> 74ms user-runtime-dir@121.service
> 62ms setvtrgb.service
> 16ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
> 12ms alsa-restore.service
> 11ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
> 2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
> 2ms sys-kernel-config.mount
> 528us snapd.socket "

Comment: I'll search the internet to get an answer for you! Please stand by!

Comment: Take a look at this! https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233133/very-long-boot-up-in-ubuntu-20-04 if this doesn't help feel free to ask for another post

Comment: Yes, i have removed NetworkManager-wait-online.service and other services related to it . Time is reduced to 1:38 min now.  Thanks for reply.